# What's the difference between Restsharp vs Restsharp.net2

Tags: c#, .net, restsharp

I've noticed that on NuGet there are two version of RestSharp. Which is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fork of Restsharp for .NET 2.0 as mentioned on the top of their [github page](https://github.com/mcintyre321/RestSharp-.NET-2.0-Fork) readme.

Comment: Ok, but do you know where to find the main differences?

Comment: I would assume that they were the same at the moment of the fork, but it hasn't been updated in a long time. So no, I don't know...